# Why does my VBA macro stop after opening and closing a few hundred CSV files?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, macros

I've written a macro that downloads zip files containing CSVs from a website. The downloading and unzipping is going perfectly, however when I try to loop through the CSVs searching for the occurrence of a specific string, the macro simply quits after opening about a thousand. There is no error message, it simply stops working, leaving the last CSV it was working on open.

Here is my code:

```
Sub OpenSearch()
Dim ROW, j As Integer

Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileNameFolder & FileListCSV(i)

For j = 1 To 7
    ROW = 3
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(ROW, 6))
    If Cells(ROW, 6) = WantedID(j, 1) Then
        MsgBox "WE HAVE A MATCH!"
    End If
    ROW = ROW + 1
    Loop
Next j

Workbooks(FileListCSV(i)).Close False
Kill FileNameFolder & FileListCSV(i)

End Sub
```

I did not include the main module that calls the this sub and downloads and unzips the files, because on its own, that works perfectly. It only stops working when the sub I copied here is being called.
The Filename comes from a public variable defined in the main module, WantedID contains the strings I need to find in the CSVs.

I've tried to put Application.Wait in the first line, but it did not solve the problem. Also how far the macro gets is completely random. It never stops after the same number of CSVs opened and closed.

UPDATE: Here is the code (parent sub) for the downloading and unzipping. I did not come up with this on my own, but copied it from an online source I cannot recall:

```
Public FileListCSV(1 To 288) As String
Public i As Integer
Public FileNameFolder As Variant
Public WantedID As Variant


Sub DownloadandUnpackFile()

Dim myURL As String
Dim YearNUM As Integer
Dim MonthNUM As Integer
Dim StarMonth, EndMonth As Integer
Dim DayNUM As Integer
Dim YearSTR As String
Dim MonthSTR As String
Dim DaySTR As String
Dim FixURL As String
Dim TargetFileName As String

Dim FSO As Object
Dim oApp As Object
Dim Fname As Variant
Dim DefPath As String
Dim strDate As String

Dim StrFile As String
Dim FileList(1 To 288) As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FixURL = "http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/ARCHIVE/Dispatch_SCADA PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_"
WantedID = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(8, 1))

YearNUM = 2016
StarMonth = 12
EndMonth = 12

For YearNUM = 2015 To 2016
    For MonthNUM = StarMonth To EndMonth

        For DayNUM = 1 To 31
            YearSTR = CStr(YearNUM)
            If MonthNUM < 10 Then
                MonthSTR = "0" & CStr(MonthNUM)
            Else:
                MonthSTR = CStr(MonthNUM)
            End If

            If DayNUM < 10 Then
                DaySTR = "0" & CStr(DayNUM)
            Else:
                DaySTR = CStr(DayNUM)
            End If

            myURL = FixURL & YearSTR & MonthSTR & DaySTR & ".zip"
            Cells(1, 1) = myURL
            Dim WinHttpReq As Object
            Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
            WinHttpReq.Send

            myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
            If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
                Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
                oStream.Open
                oStream.Type = 1
                oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
                TargetFileName = "C:\Users\istvan.szabo\Documents   \Basslink\AEMO RAW DATA\RAWRAW\" & YearSTR & MonthSTR & DaySTR & ".zip"
                oStream.SaveToFile (TargetFileName)
                oStream.Close
             End If

        'try unzippin'

            Fname = TargetFileName
                If Fname = False Then
        'Do nothing
            Else
                'Root folder for the new folder.
                'You can also use DefPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test\"
                 DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
                If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
                    DefPath = DefPath & "\"
                 End If

                FileNameFolder = "C:\Users\istvan.szabo\Documents\Basslink\AEMO RAW DATA\RAWRAW\" & YearSTR & MonthSTR & DaySTR
                'Make the normal folder in DefPath
                MkDir FileNameFolder

                'Extract the files into the newly created folder
                 Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

                 oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).items

                On Error Resume Next
                Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
                FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
                i = 1
                StrFile = Dir(FileNameFolder & "\")
                    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
                        FileList(i) = FileNameFolder & "\" & StrFile
                        FileListCSV(i) = Left(StrFile, Len(StrFile) - 3) & "csv"
                        StrFile = Dir
                         i = i + 1
                     Loop
                 'unzip the unzipped
                For i = 1 To 288
                     Fname = FileList(i)
                     If Fname = False Then
                     'Do nothing
                    Else:
                        DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
                        If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
                            DefPath = DefPath & "\"
                         End If
                         FileNameFolder = "C:\Users\istvan.szabo\Documents\Basslink\AEMO RAW DATA\"
                         Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                         oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).items
                         On Error Resume Next
                        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
                        FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
                        Call OpenSearch
                    End If
                Next i
            End If

        Next DayNUM
    Next MonthNUM
    StarMonth = 1
    EndMonth = 5
 Next YearNUM

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: If its not too big could you drop the parent sub in too? It sounds like a memory error.

Comment: How large are these files?  Any error handler(s) in the calling methods?

Comment: @GaryEvans: I've included the parent sub too now. It's medium big I guess...@Tim Williams: The files are 16 KB each. I could not really decide on the approach of error handling. I'd be open for suggestions!

Comment: Are you expecting many matches and are you expecting (many) matches in other columns? If not, it might be faster to look through the files as text files (I don't know what the overhead is on opening a CSV as a workbook and dealing with a workbook compared to a FileSystemObject and string so it's just an idea)

Comment: Thanks arcadeprecinct! I am expecting quite a lot of matches, but it is only the sixth column (how ironic) I need to check. There's the ID that I need a match with. Speed is not in issue for me. I don't mind if the macro runs for a whole day as long as it gives me the results and doesn't just stop working whenever it pleases.

Comment: @IstvánSzabó Well speed is no issue for you once it works but if you have to wait an hour before your code fails instead of a few seconds, that slows you down quite a bit when figuring out the problem ;). First thing you should do is disable the error handler. `On Error Resume Next` causes the macro to just continue if an error occurred instead of telling you! Then try to understand what the code does (if you don't already have) and if you really need everything that happens in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the file without opening it. That would save you time and resources. Here is a quick draw of the code I would use:

```
Sub OpenSearch()

Dim ROW, j As Integer
Dim fileID
Dim buf As String
Dim tmp As Variant

Open FileNameFolder & FileListCSV(i) For Input As #1

For j = 1 To 7

    ROW = 3

    Do Until EOF(1)

        Line Input #1, buf

        'Remove double quotes
        buf = Replace(buf, """", "")

        'Split line to a array
        tmp = Split(buf, ",")

        '5 is the 6th column in excel tmp index starts with 0
        fileID = tmp(5)

        If fileID = WantedID(j, 1) Then
            MsgBox "WE HAVE A MATCH!"
        End If

    ROW = ROW + 1

    Loop

Next j

Close #1

Kill FileNameFolder & FileListCSV(i)

End Sub
```

EDIT: Also try to add a resource cleanup code, for example: `Set WinHttpReq = Nothing, Set oStream = Nothing` etc.

Comment: Thank you Dawid! At "Open FileNameFolder & FileListCSV(i) For Input As #1" it gives me the error message "Invalid outside procedure". Should I reference something before running it?

Comment: Could you please debug print the `FileNameFolder & FileListCSV(i)` variables to check how your path and file name looks like?

Answer (score 1):

In line with other advice in the comments: -

- You should close of resources when you are done with them using `Set WinHttpReq = Nothing` for example. This can avoid memory problems that are similar to the issue you are seeing.
- It is also advisable to remove `On Error Resume Next`. This is hiding errors and you may well be missing results that you need. It would also allow for more information during errors.

I took your two code blocks and wrote them into one that I believe will be stable during running and make it to the end, Run this and let us know if it did resolve the issue. I did it this way as there was a lot of small changes that went towards what I suspect will be more stable and make it to the end.

```
Sub DownloadandUnpackFile()
Dim FSO             As New FileSystemObject
Dim DteDate         As Date
Dim Fl              As File
Dim Fl_Root         As File
Dim Fldr            As Folder
Dim Fldr_Root       As Folder
Dim LngCounter      As Long
Dim LngCounter2     As Long
Dim oApp            As Object
Dim oStream         As Object
Dim oWinHttpReq     As Object
Dim RngIDs          As Range
Dim StrURL          As String
Dim StrRootURL      As String
Dim VntFile         As Variant
Dim VntFolder       As Variant
Dim VntRootFile     As Variant
Dim VntRootFolder   As Variant
Dim WkBk            As Workbook
Dim WkSht           As Worksheet

'This will speed up processing, but you might not see progress while it is working
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set variables
StrRootURL = "http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/ARCHIVE/Dispatch_SCADA/PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_"

'You should be a little more explicit here for clarity, refernce a worksheet
'E.g. StrID = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(8, 1))
Set RngIDs = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(8, 1))

Set oWinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

'Loop from 21/Feb/2015 to today
For DteDate = CDate("21/Feb/2015") To Date
    StrURL = StrRootURL & Format(DteDate, "YYYYMMDD") & ".zip"

    Debug.Print StrURL

    oWinHttpReq.Open "GET", StrURL, False
    oWinHttpReq.Send
    StrURL = oWinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    If oWinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            oStream.Open
            oStream.Type = 1
            oStream.Write oWinHttpReq.ResponseBody
            VntRootFile = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\Basslink\AEMO RAW DATA\RAWRAW\" & Format(DteDate, "YYYYMMDD") & ".zip"
            oStream.SaveToFile VntRootFile
            oStream.Close
        Set oStream = Nothing

        VntRootFolder = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\Basslink\AEMO RAW DATA\RAWRAW\" & Format(DteDate, "YYYYMMDD") & "\"
        FSO.CreateFolder VntRootFolder

        oApp.Namespace(VntRootFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(VntRootFile).Items

        Set Fldr_Root = FSO.GetFolder(VntRootFolder)

            'Unzip the zipped zips
            For Each Fl_Root In Fldr_Root.Files
                If Right(LCase(Fl_Root.Name), 4) = ".zip" Then
                    VntFolder = Fl_Root.ParentFolder & "\" & Left(Fl_Root.Name, Len(Fl_Root.Name) - 4) & "\"
                    FSO.CreateFolder VntFolder
                    VntFile = Fl_Root.Path
                    oApp.Namespace(VntFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(VntFile).Items

                    Set Fldr = FSO.GetFolder(VntFolder)

                        For Each Fl In Fldr.Files
                            If Right(LCase(Fl.Name), 4) = ".csv" Then
                                Set WkBk = Application.Workbooks.Open(Fl.Path)
                                    Set WkSht = WkBk.Worksheets(1)
                                        For LngCounter = 1 To RngIDs.Rows.Count
                                            LngCounter2 = 1
                                            Do Until WkSht.Cells(LngCounter2, 6) = ""
                                                If WkSht.Cells(LngCounter2, 6) = RngIDs.Cells(LngCounter, 1) Then
                                                    Debug.Print "FOUND: " & Fl.Name & ": " & WkSht.Cells(LngCounter2, 6).Address
                                                End If
                                                LngCounter2 = LngCounter2 + 1
                                            Loop
                                        Next
                                    Set WkSht = Nothing
                                    WkBk.Close 0
                                Set WkBk = Nothing
                            End If
                            DoEvents
                        Next

                    Set Fldr = Nothing
                End If
            Next
            Fldr_Root.Delete True
        Set Fldr_Root = Nothing

        FSO.DeleteFile VntRootFile, True

    End If
    DoEvents
Next

Set oApp = Nothing
Set oWinHttpReq = Nothing
Set RngIDs = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Changes I have made: -

- I used early binding to `FileSystemObject` simply to make it easier
  to write up. You will need the 'Windows Scripting Runtime' reference
  added (Tools > References > tick 'Windows Scripting Runtime')
- I iterated through dates as a single loop rather then three loops of
  strings working as a date
- I set IDs to be a range and note a variant
- I opened references once, reuse them (i.e. `oApp`), and then close
  them
- I added `DoEvents` to give time back to the computer to run anything it
  may need to, this maintains a health system.
- I used Debug.Print to add information to the immediate window instead
  of msgbox, but you should really list the finds out in a separate
  worksheet, (debug.print has a size limit so you may end up only
  seeing *X* number of results as others are truncated off.

Comment: Thank you Gary! I started running the code, but unfortunately at line "FSO.DeleteFile StrRootFile, True" it stopped with an error "Invalid procedure call or argument". (I made sure to add the reference you mentioned.)

Comment: @IstvánSzabó Change `FSO.DeleteFile StrRootFile, True` to `FSO.DeleteFile VntRootFile, True`